# D3 v7 timeScale paning and zooming from-to date limit

Tags: javascript, d3.js

D3 v7 timeScale pan and zoom from-to date limit

Hello everyone
I have an issue.
I need to have a time scale for a custom video player with limited dates.
For ex. from 2021, 1, 1 to Date.now
My code is:

```
    const domainStart = new Date(2021, 1, 1)
    const domainEnd = new Date()

    const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([new Date(domainEnd.getTime() - (30*60*1000)), domainEnd])
      .range([0, width]);

    const zoomMin = 1;
    const zoomMax = (domainEnd.getTime() - domainStart.getTime()) / (1000 * 60)

    const zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([zoomMin, zoomMax])
      .on('zoom', (event) => {
        const transformer = event.transform.rescaleX(xScale2)
        axis.scale(transformer)
        axisG.call(axis)
      });

    const svg = d3.select('#scale')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .call(zoom)

    const axis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)

    const axisG = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'x-axis')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
      .call(axis)
```

The question is:
How can I limit scale zooming and panning between two dates? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I handled this issue. the solution:

```
const margin = {top: 0, right: 20, bottom: 60, left: 20}
const width = 600;
const height = 100;

const domainStart = new Date('2022-01-10T00:00:01')
const domainEnd = new Date()

const xScale: ScaleTime<number, number> = d3
  .scaleTime()
  .domain([domainStart, domainEnd])
  .rangeRound([0, width])

const zoomMin = 1;
const zoomMax = (domainEnd.getTime() - domainStart.getTime()) / (1000 * 60);

const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([zoomMin, zoomMax])
  .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .on('zoom', ({transform}) => {
    axis.scale(transform.rescaleX(xScale))
    axisG.call(axis)
  });

const svg = d3.select('#scale')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .call(zoom)

const axis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)

const axisG = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x-axis')
  .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
  .call(axis);

const k = (domainEnd.getTime() - domainStart.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 30);
const centerDate = xScale.invert((width) / 2);

zoom.scaleTo(svg, k)
zoom.translateTo(svg, centerDate.getTime(), 0)
```